# Run Two Instances of RStudio Server via Docker

Tags: docker, rstudio

I'm trying to run multiple instances of RStudio Server (community version) on a single machine using Docker, but am running into some issues.

I'm using the [rocker/rstudio](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio) container.

Here's what I'm running to start the containers:

```
$ docker run -d -p 9001:8787 -e PASSWORD=password rocker/rstudio
$ docker run -d -p 9002:8787 -e PASSWORD=password rocker/rstudio
```

When I go to `localhost:9001`, I can sign as the "rstudio" user and run a couple statements in RStudio. *BUT* when I open a new tab and go to `localhost:9002`, I see the login screen. It fails when I try to login, and also kicks me out of the `9001` session.

I thought because the RStudio sessions are in different containers they could run in parallel, but there seems to be something going on preventing this approach.

Does anyone know a potential workaround to this? [This article](https://sbamin.com/blog/2016/02/running_rstudio_in_docker_environment/) describes a similar approach, but was written in 2016 so I'm guessing things have changed since then.

Comment: This could very much look like cookie issues (one might override the other cookies), try running one in a normal window and another in a private one

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Comment: I've posted this as an answer, you can accept it using the checkmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that cookies are the issue here, one instance will override the other's cookies, you can run one of the instance on a normal window and another in a private one

Answer (score 0):

I tried that and using two different browsers but it still didn't "work."

[image]